# Using RESULT_SCAN() to retrieve multiple query results from inside a stored procedure

Tags: pyspark, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using pyspark in Databricks on Azure to run queries against Snowflake. I have a stored procedure in Snowflake that runs many individual queries (creates, drops, updates, inserts, selects, etc).

I have a pyspark notebook in Databricks that calls the stored procedure with some parameters. I am working on creating logging and monitoring of this notebook by using the Session QUERY_TAG field to tag all of the queries that run in the current session with the same name so I can find them easily when I select * from table(the information_schema.query_history()). So far this is working exactly as expected.

The issue is when I try to use the QUERY_ID from the query_history in select * from table(RESULT_SCAN(<query_id>)). All of the queries that ran inside the stored procedure do not seem to exist in the RESULT_SCAN table. Or rather, I get errors when I try to pass the query_id of the queries that ran inside the stored procedure to the RESULT_SCAN. Any query that ran in the Databricks notebook outside of the stored procedure call come back with results.

Does anybody know how I can get the results of the queries that ran inside the stored procedure without having to update the stored procedure itself? Or if this is even possible? Does Snowflake store this information or because these queries run inside the stored procedure, does Snowflake only store the results of the stored procedure call and not the individual queries inside of the stored procedure?

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the stored procedure to add logic that would allow me to log/return the results of the queries run inside of it.

I have been searching the internet and conferring with my co-workers.

So far I haven't found any specific documentation or forums where others have encountered this issue or have needed/wanted to do this. All of the examples I've seen use very simple stored procedures with a single select statement and return values.

Comment: Snowflake stored procedures execute with owner's rights by default. Unless the author explicitly specified to run with caller's rights, it's possible that the user calling the SP does not have sufficient privileges to select on the result set. The author(s) of the SP can check to see if the SP can run with caller's rights, and then the result_scan results should be selectable.

Comment: You are correct sir. That is what we figured out. Someone else had posted a solution and I made a comment to that effect but it looks like the solution was deleted. At any rate, I have a coworker who said he is going to post our findings as a solution to make sure it can help others. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.